# Unable to install OpenBabel package

Tags: python, pip, package

I am working on building a python script that tests the binding affinity of protein-ligand pairs generated by our ML model as positive/negative binding annotations. One of the steps in doing so requires the download of .SDF files from PubChem, and in order to prepare them for autodocking they need to be converted to .PDB files. The only real solution that I have found has been using OpenBabel to convert the file type, but I am completely unable to install the package on my computer. Whether or not I have the latest package downloaded, every time I type `pip install openbabel` I recieve the following error message:

```
Installing collected packages: openbabel
  Running setup.py install for openbabel ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pnt2eol5\\openbabel\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pnt2eol5\\openbabel\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-enmjb591\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pnt2eol5\openbabel\
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    running build_ext
    Warning: invalid version number '3.1.1.1'.
    Guessing Open Babel location:
    - include_dirs: ['c:\\users\\chris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\include', 'c:\\users\\chris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\include', '/usr/local/include/openbabel3']
    - library_dirs: ['c:\\users\\chris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs', 'c:\\users\\chris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\PCbuild\\amd64', '/usr/local/lib']
    building 'openbabel._openbabel' extension
    swigging openbabel\openbabel-python.i to openbabel\openbabel-python_wrap.cpp
    swig.exe -python -c++ -small -O -templatereduce -naturalvar -Ic:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -I/usr/local/include/openbabel3 -o openbabel\openbabel-python_wrap.cpp openbabel\openbabel-python.i

    Error: SWIG failed. Is Open Babel installed?
    You may need to manually specify the location of Open Babel include and library directories. For example:
      python setup.py build_ext -I/usr/local/include/openbabel3 -L/usr/local/lib
      python setup.py install
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pnt2eol5\\openbabel\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pnt2eol5\\openbabel\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-enmjb591\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried compiling the program myself, and using conda to install the program, and I am still receiving similar errors.

Comment: Is Open Babel installed?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have installed the OpenBabel software, and then, download the wheel from [Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#openbabel)

[image: this repo link]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is because pypi, `openbabel==3.1.1.1` is built for win and this is a wrong wheel. Try:

```
pip install openbabel-wheel
```

It might work, at least it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't found an exact solution to this issue, but try to reach the url https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages.

If you're not able to (which is what happened with me), it is most probably a network error.

I changed my network and I was able to continue using pip install commands on terminal.

Comment: pip is already running `setup.py`, so no way that this is an issue with downloading the package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Try using the command

pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org [package name]. Make note to run this as administrator, or if you're using a mac system to add sudo command before it

Comment: Unfortunately I recieve the same error message, maybe it has something to do with the package itself?

Comment: pip is already running `setup.py`, so no way that this is an issue with downloading the package. Running pip as root is also terrible advice

Comment: The issue isnt about network approaching